# Returning Promise with handlers

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

If we have the following inside a function:

```
return fetch('#exampleUrl').then(result => result + 1);
```

Are we returning the first promise (returned by fetch)?

Or does it wait for fetch to resolve, then return the promise returned by the `then` handler?

Comment: You will get instantly a promise back which is not yet fulfilled. Then, as soon as fetch **and** the then() is resolved, your promise will resolve to the return value from within the then(). This describes the success case. In case of an error in fetch(), the then() won't be executed.

Answer (score 0):

The short and direct answer to your question : It will return the first promise. Here is an example :

```js
function func(url) {
    return fetch(url)  // return this promise
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => (json.results))
}

func('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10')
.then(users => console.log(users))
```